# Run a pig script with specific version

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I have two pig versions as 0.11 and 0.15 on the hadoop gateway. Default version set by hadoop admin is 0.11. I want to run a pig script with version 0.15 without changing the cluster settings.
Please guide how can i run my pig script(say hello.pig) using pig 0.15 and not pig 0.11.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following parameter:

```
-useversion 0.15
```